# A general question in type of computer science

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

Where can I find a source for questions/problems with data structures (like questions about avl trees , rank-trees, 2-3 trees, heap) and algorithms?

I will be happy for a references in these topics (I tried to search it in google,but I don't find appropriate something).

Comment: Of interest: Not an exact answer so a comment. Searching for [99 programming problems](https://www.google.com/search?q=99+programming+problems&oq=99+programming+problems&aqs=chrome..69i57.1111j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) would be a start, e.g. [H-99: Ninety-Nine Haskell Problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems)

Comment: Of interest: Another ball park comment: The task list for [RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a web portal that helps all computer scientists by selecting what level you're in i.e. Medium,expert...
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org

Since data structures and algorithms are quite many,hoping you will do what best suits your computational problems.